# Returning on ISNULL decimal "0,00"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

Hello I have got this query that I would like to return '0,00' insead of '0'

When I tried to write it like this:

```
string sqlcom = "SELECT (ISNULL(s_prijmy, 0,00)), * FROM zajezd WHERE akce >= '" + txt_od.Text + "'AND akce <='" + txt_do.Text + "' AND rocnik='" + klientClass.Rocnik() + "'";
```

It gives me following Exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Decimal()

May I ask how can I fix it ?

Thanks in adavance.

Future use of this '0,00' should be following :

```
this.chart1.Series["Příjmy"].Points.AddXY(myreader.GetString(myreader.GetOrdinal("akce")), myreader.GetDecimal(34).ToString()); // the 34th column
```

Comment: Although not an answer I should point out that you should use parameters and do not concat SQL strings with the values you want.

Comment: I remember that some guys gave you some advice about using `SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue` instead (to avoid `SQL injection`) but you still use `string concatenation`?

Comment: You are confused between value and its presentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0,00` is not decimal. Try `0.00` to cast it into the decimal in your query. And don't forgot to put `0.00` in single quotes `''` if `s_prijmy` is type of `varchar`.

Try this

```
string sqlcom = "SELECT (ISNULL(s_prijmy, '0.00')), * FROM zajezd WHERE akce >= '" + txt_od.Text + "'AND akce <='" + txt_do.Text + "' AND rocnik='" + klientClass.Rocnik() + "'";
```

And yes as I already said the please try to use parameterized query.

Comment: I've edited my question, may you please check it? I tried what you proposed but still got the same exception.

Answer (score 3):

Change `,` with `.` in your query.

```
ISNULL(s_prijmy, 0.00)
```

I would also note that

```
GetDecimal(34)
```

gets the 35th column as it is zero-based...

Use:

```
GetDecimal(33)
```

for the 34th column.

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdecimal.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

What datatype is s_prijmy?  if it is string, and you want to return a string of '0.00' then do

```
 ISNULL(s_prijmy, '0.00')
```

If it is numeric, and you want to return a number in format  0.00, then do

```
ISNULL(s_prijmy, cast(0 as decimal(3,2)))
```

if s_prijmy has a greater precision that 2, eg decimal(4,3), then you will get 0.000

Comment: Thanks for your answer: the s_prijmy is : numeric(10, 2)

Comment: then go with ISNULL(s_prijmy, cast(0 as decimal(3,2)))

Comment: Thanks but still got the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
string sqlcom = "SELECT cast(ISNULL(s_prijmy, 0) as decimal(8,2)), * FROM zajezd WHERE akce >= '" + txt_od.Text + "'AND akce <='" + txt_do.Text + "' AND rocnik='" + klientClass.Rocnik() + "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can format the data when you display it.

select the data as it is

```
string sqlcom = "SELECT s_prijmy, .........
```

then

```
var value = myreader.GetString(myreader.GetOrdinal("s_prijmy"));

value =  string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)?"0,00":value;
```

now you can use above value in `Points.AddXY`

Answer (score 1):

You must correct your presentation at client side. Look at the [public string ToString(string format)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx). Also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).